# Iptables won't redirect

Tags: linux, iptables, routing, ip, nat

I'm trying to redirect all tcp traffic on port 102 from a single ip address to another ip address and want to masquerade the ip as well

im using this iptable config, but still i cannot connect.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 195.190.131.189 -d 195.190.131.180 -p tcp --dport 102 -j DNAT --to 192.168.251.10:102
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 102 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -p tcp --dport 102 -j LOG --log-level 2
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1  -p tcp --dport 102 -j LOG --log-level 2
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT 1      -p tcp --dport 102 -j LOG --log-level 2
```

The iptable -t nat -L -nv shows

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 292 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    3   152 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:102 LOG flags 0 level 2
    3   152 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       195.190.131.189      195.190.131.180     tcp dpt:102 to:192.168.251.10:102

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 11 packets, 660 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:102 LOG flags 0 level 2
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:102

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 11 packets, 660 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:102 LOG flags 0 level 2


Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:102 LOG flags 0 level 2
```

So from my understanding, the packet are sent to the DNAT.

Is it a problem that the message log does not show an output interface:

```
Sep 24 20:14:28 appsgh kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:8a:70:12:00:50:56:8a:74:02:08:00 SRC=195.190.131.189 DST=195.190.131.180 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=6511 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53696 DPT=102 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Sep 24 20:19:18 appsgh kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:8a:70:12:00:50:56:8a:74:02:08:00 SRC=195.190.131.189 DST=195.190.131.180 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=6701 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53709 DPT=102 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Sep 24 20:19:21 appsgh kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:8a:70:12:00:50:56:8a:74:02:08:00 SRC=195.190.131.189 DST=195.190.131.180 LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=6703 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53709 DPT=102 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Sep 24 20:19:27 appsgh kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:50:56:8a:70:12:00:50:56:8a:74:02:08:00 SRC=195.190.131.189 DST=195.190.131.180 LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=128 ID=6707 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53709 DPT=102 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you want to do this?
{Client}(port_random)-----(port12345){you}(port_random)-----(port4321){111.111.111.111}

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 12345 -j DNAT --to-destination 111.111.111.111:4321
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 111.111.111.111 --dport 4321 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 111.111.111.111 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I don't know why somebody down voted this answer since @atitan made a valid point that you need to allow FORWARDing to make what the OP requested work.  And the original post shows nothing re: the FORWARD chain, which is likely where packets are dropped.